# I have JavaScript code missing and don't know how to write it.

Tags: javascript, typeerror, referenceerror

I have looked at examples and can't quite find exactly what I am looking for to fix my issue.

The site is www.markdektor.com. A light box is supposed to fire off when you click on the image links, but that is not happening. It worked fine until I went live with it. I am just learning JavaScript. Someone helped me with the JavaScript but left a couple incomplete parts I believe, and now I can't figure out what should be written to fix the issue.

When I use inspect element in Chrome it tells me there is an uncaught reference error and highlightPage is not defined in my custom JavaScript on line 53 and an uncaught typeError because 'dispatchEvent' object has no method in my JavaScript prototype on line 3971.

Someone please tell me what I can write to fix this.

If you need more information, please leave a comment asking for it.

Comment: It looks as though normalize.css, plugins.js and main.js are all missing. Have they been uploaded to your live server?

Comment: nope.. i didnt have them before i uploaded.  can i just cut and paste those files from boilerplate or something?

Comment: I added those files from boiler plate.. it didnt resolve the issue.. is there a better way i can ask this question?

Comment: Well thank you for editing my grammar and spelling. Is there any chance you could spend an equal amount of effort in resolving my scripting issue?

Comment: Does your working dev environment have any of the same js errors?

Since highlightPage isn't defined anywhere you should try and find all of the places it occurs in your working dev environment and then look for it in the same places in your live environment and hopefully that will show you some things that are missing.

Comment: I will try.. thank you.. Im just thinking that its calling for events that were never specified. And im not sure what to do about it. I appreciate all the help.